# Error with cv.glm function

Tags: r, package, glm

I am trying to use the cv.glm function to run a LOOCV with a logistic regression. I am using the following code:

```
library(boot)
cost <- function(r, pi = 0) mean(abs(r-pi) > 0.5)
lr1 <- glm(lineupacc~confidenceresp, family="binomial", data=data)
cross <- cv.glm(data, lr1, cost=cost)
```

When I try to run this function I get a whole lot of warnings, each reading as follows:

```
In r - pi : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: are there `NA`s in your data? what does `sum(is.na(data))` return?

Comment: Yes, in the predictor variable there are 3 missing values.

Comment: cv.glm can't handle missing values - you'll have to omit or recode them.

Comment: Thanks for the help!